# SQL Query with Limit doesn't work in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I put this sql code in PHPMYADMIN **to display the first 4 rows**, **but it display all the 43 rows of my table**. I have no idea why.
Please help !

Here is the query :

```
  SELECT  * FROM `myTable` 
    natural JOIN `column1` 
    natural JOIN `column2` 
  WHERE `mytable`.`something` = 1 
  ORDER BY mytable_date DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour... although column1 is a decidedly odd name for a table.

Comment: Sorry I worked with mysql

Comment: @techspider phpmyadmin is a MySQL web based gui 

There was a bug, https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3539/    in phpmyadmin that is now fixed, perhaps you have an older version of phpmyadmin?  If so, remove the ORDER BY to see if you get just 4 results

Comment: Many thanks @DuaneLortie for answering me. But when I removed the ORDER BY, phpmyadmin still displaying all the table rows. Moreover, I worked with MariaDB version: 10.1.13, which I think , is a very recent version.

Comment: Does it work correctly from the command-line client?

Comment: Thanks @IsaacBennetch for your answer. I've already solve my problem. In fact, when I run the code with phpmyadmin, it doesn't work. But when I run it from the server (php) it works great. I don't know why, but it's ok because the most important for me is the server side.

Comment: I've done quite a few tests and haven't been able to reproduce this either. I know you've already worked around it, but I'd be curious about which phpMyAdmin version you were using.

Comment: phpmyadmin version  4.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I think this *may* be because phpMyAdmin modifies SELECT statements, adding it's own LIMIT clause:  It may be replacing your LIMIT with its own, for some reason.

phpMyAdmin inserts a LIMIT because by default it paginates the result of a SELECT when you view it in the GUI, it doesn't show all rows right away for large tables (there's a checkbox you can click to do that, once the initial first page of results is displayed).

It's not always really clever about it though:  I've just run into a related difficulty where it was inserting a LIMIT clause into a subquery with FOR UPDATE, which MariaDB doesn't allow... and it was giving me an error.

So you have to remember when using phpMyAdmin, that it adds LIMIT clauses to your SQL, it isn't sent to the database as-is.

I think there might be an option somewhere to turn this behavior off, but OTOH I don't know where that is.  (If someone knows, please point it out in the comments!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT and OFFSET for this.
In your case you just need LIMIT, because you're starting since 0.

```
SELECT  * FROM `myTable` 
natural JOIN `column1` 
natural JOIN `column2` 
WHERE `mytable`.`something` = 1 
ORDER BY mytable_date DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0;
```

or simpler

```
 ORDER BY mytable_date DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Thousand thanks @Allanh for answering me, but sadly, my issue remains, phpmyadmin still displaying all the table rows.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with all your tables ? what happens if you try with `SELECT  * FROM mytable LIMIT 4` you should test with another tables. tell me about results.

Comment: Yes unfortunately